# sourcing a setup.bash in a Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to build me a Dockerfile for my ROS project.
In ROS it is required that you source a setup bash in every terminal before starting to work.

(You can replace this by putting the source command in your bashrc file)

So, what I do is to source the file in the Dockerfle so that it gets run when the container is built.  It works fine *on that terminal*

However when I open another terminal , predictably it seems that that file is not sourced and I have to do it manually.

Is there any way I can avoid this?

As I said in a non docker way, you put this into a file that gets called everytime a terminal is open but how do you do this with docker?

(in other words, how do you make sure a sh file is executed everytime I execute (or attach to) a docker container)

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile, copy your script to Docker `WORKDIR`:

```
COPY  ./setup.bash .
```

Then set the entry point to run that script at container launch:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./setup.bash"]
```

Note that with this approach, you won't be able to start your container in an interactive terminal with `docker run -it`. You'll need to do a few more things if that's what you want. Also, this will overwrite your original image's `ENTRYPOINT` (which you can find by `docker image history`), so make sure that is not essential. Otherwise, sourcing the script may be the better option for both cases:

```
RUN source ./setup.bash
```

Comment: `RUN source ./setup.bash` makes no sense - the changes will only be visible up until the end of the shell, which will be immediately terminated...

Comment: @KamilCuk actually it does. In my case I source the file and then when I `docker run` the container I finish with `/bin/bash` and in that environment the file is sourced. The problem is that that does not extend to other terminals where I `exec` the container

Answer (score 0):

Just add the script to startup configuration files in bash...

```
COPY ./setup.bash /etc/
RUN echo "source /etc/setup.bash" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

The file `/etc/bash.bashrc` might be named `/etc/bashrc`, or you might want to use `/etc/profile.d` directory, depending if you want the file to be sourced in interactive shells or not. Read the relevant documentation about startup files in bash.